# What method is more appropriate in this case?

Tags: jquery

I want to get some data of the selected user in the select with name ="user" to populate some form fields
based on the data of the returned user. My doubt is if the method should be post or get because in this case it is necessary to get user data based on the Id of the selected option. So it seems correct to use $.get, however, I don't know if its also correct with $.post and if in this case its equal to use use one or another. Do you know which is the appropriate method in this case?

jQuery:

```
$(function () {

       $('select[name="user"]').change(function () {

       var user = $(this);

       $.post(user.data('action'), {user: user.val()}, function (response) {

         ....

        }, 'json');
    })
 });
```

Comment: Technically you can use both. But the intended use of these methods is given away by their names: "get" should be used, if you essentially want to get something from the server. Of course, you will have to send the `id` as a parameter, but the main purpose is to *get* information, You should use "post" when you want to transfer data (small or large) to the server. The length of a URL is limted, so "get" will run out of steam if you try to transfer too much data in one go.

Comment: The *correct* method is `GET` as you're...well... getting information.  POST is save and PUT is save in a specific place.  However, most of the internet was built before people realised we should be using those so they only really matter if you're creating a true REST api.  There are also technical differences, GET doesn't have a body, so if you have a large amount of data in the GET request you used to have to do a POST to send it (not so much now as urls are longer)

Comment: To clarify @cars10m comment above, get is limited on the *request*, not the response - so to clarify: "transfer too much data [to the server]".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.